# Return Generic Type after determining Type Parameter dynamically

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class as shown below

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to return the instance of this type with the type parameter being determined at run time, something as shown below

```
public MyClass<object> ReturnWithDynamicParameterType()
{
    //This function determines the type of T at runtime and should return instance of MyClass<T>
}
```

How this can be accomplished

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve - the real problem.

Comment: Classes are invariant so you won't be able to return a `MyClass<T>` as a `MyClass<object>`. Even if they were, the setter on `MyProp` would prevent `MyClass<T>` from being covariant in `T`.

Comment: Apart from the return type being incorrect, you can't, unless you have a definitive list of types that T could be. Each particular MyClass<T> is generated at compile time. So you would need to create the list in the ReturnWithDynamicParameterType() method.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is **not possible**.  While you can create a generic type for an arbitrary generic type argument at runtime like this

```
public MyClass<object> ReturnWithDynamicParameterType(Type genericArgument)
{
    Type genericType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(genericArgument);
    return (MyClass<object>)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
}
```

this `return` line will always throw an `InvalidCastException`. As Lee already commented, classes are invariant. This means that for example `MyClass<object>` and `MyClass<string>` are simply **not the same types**. They are **not even inherited** from one another.

Even co-variance won't help since the `out` keyword is not allowed for generic parameters in classes.

I don't see a solution for this without knowing the types at compile-time. But I'm sure that you can solve what you are *actually* trying to achieve by other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this fits your use, but your only way out is the use of an interface that is covariant.

```
public interface IMyClass<out T>
{
    T MyProp { get; }
}

public class MyClass<T> : IMyClass<T>
{
    public T MyProp { get; set; }
}

public IMyClass<object> ReturnWithDynamicParameterType()
{
    //This function determines the type of T at runtime and should return instance of MyClass<T>

    return new MyClass<string>();
}
```

This code compiles because your return type is not a class, but a covariant interface (note the `out T` on the type parameter). That interface allows retrieval only, so the `get;set` on the property has been replaced by a get on the interface.

Comment: Right, I tried that too but did not include it in my answer since you cannot declare the setter in the interface (because it would need contra-variance). +1 anyway for it's the only way coming close to what was asked for.